# I can not see any images comes from firebase storage on tableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I can not see any images comes from firebase storage on tableView, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseStorageUI

class TariflerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var TariflerTableView: UITableView!  
    var count = 8  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    private func numberOfSections (_ tableView: UITableView)-> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(in tableView : UITableView)-> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.TariflerTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Tariflercell",for : indexPath) as! TariflerTableViewCell

        let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://aaaa-d3253.appspot.com")
        let imagePath = "KAHVE(\(count)).jpg"
        let url = storage.child(imagePath) 
        url.downloadURL ( completion : {(url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }
                guard let imageData = UIImage(data : data!) else{
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageViewy.image = imageData
                }}).resume()
        }
        )   
        count -= 1
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this line of code is being run `cell.imageViewy.image = imageData`? Try setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: yes, this line is true i checked it.

Comment: Check your imageViewy in TariflerTableViewCell